# What is one word to describe someone who plans and manages and whom one consults about a new plant/factory?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want one word to describe a guy who is a manager, a planner, and a consultant for new startup factories or plants.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Start-up manager/consultant ?

Answer (score 2):

Factory launch (project) manager, the activities you describe are all part of what a (project) manager does anyways. Alternatively it could be a factory start-up project manager. Or something along those lines.

> ***project manager NOUN*** The person in overall charge of the planning and execution of a particular project. [-ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/project-manager?q=project+manager)